# Linux Network Device Driver

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am writing Linux driver for I/O data transfer. The data transfer should be through network communication. So,  I need transfer data from kernel to Ethernet port. The Ethernet port connected to network I/O control hardware. How can i implement?. How can i write driver for that?

Comment: look at existing drivers that do the same thing and modify them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually network I/O controller hardware is connected to PCI based RTL8139 card via Ethernet cable. shall i modify the RTL8139 driver or any other method possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Read "Network Drivers" section of the Linux Device Drivers book (Chapter 17 of 3-rd Edition).
2. Look at existing network drivers.
3. Learn specifics of the hardware you are using.
4. Implement a driver for your hardware.

If you are not familiar with other aspects of kernel development (like PCIe, for example) then I recommend you read the whole book. You can buy one, or read it online, here — http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually network I/O controller hardware is connected to PCI based RTL8139 card via Ethernet cable. shall i modify the RTL8139 driver or any other method possible?